# solution instead of stored procedure in SQL Server 2008

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a database which has many stored procedure which execute in the first of month. They should read based on rules from some tables and insert calculated results  on other table. There are huge number of queries. Can I find another better solution instead of stored procedures?
SQL Server 2008

Comment: Standard way of doing this are stored procedures, in business organizations such as banks where they have extensive monthly calculations they usually have SQL Server jobs that periodically run stored procedures to do these calculations. I would say that stored procedures fit your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really wanted to you could write a service (e.g. windows service) to do the work but I would suggest stored procedures are probably best. This of course does depend on what the procedures do.

Comment: I think windows service is not good solution becuase add one step to processing. We should connect to sql. but with store procedure it execute directly.

Comment: @Ramezanir. I agree. I was simply providing an alterate, but I did state "stored procedures are probably best".